# Flattening a list of lists - Conversion type mismatch

Tags: java, list, type-conversion

I'm implementing an iterator to flatten a list of lists, but it gives me an error which I cannot understand why it happens :

The error is : 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from `java.util.Iterator<java.util.List<T>>` to `java.util.Iterator<java.util.List<T>>`

I am confused , why does it try to convert a type to itself ? and why doesn't it succeed ? Is it because it's being used in the inner class ?

```
public class FlattenList<T> implements Iterable<T>{
    private List<List<T>> lists;
    public FlattenList(List<List<T>> list){
        this.lists = list;
    }
    public Iterator<T> iterator(){
        return new ListIterator();
    }
    class ListIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>{
        private Iterator<List<T>> listsiterator;
        private Iterator<T> listiterator;
        public ListIterator(){
            if (lists != null)
                listsiterator = lists.iterator(); // The conversion mismatch here
            }
        }
            //..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually two different type parameters in your code. Both are called `T`, so the inner one shadows the outer. But they are definitely not the same. Your code is equivalent to this:

```
public class FlattenList<T> implements Iterable<T>{
    private List<List<T>> lists;
    public FlattenList(List<List<T>> list){
        this.lists = list;
    }
    public Iterator<T> iterator(){
        return new ListIterator();
    }
    class ListIterator<E> implements Iterator<E>{
        private Iterator<List<E>> listsiterator;
        private Iterator<E> listiterator;
        public ListIterator(){
            if (lists != null) {
                listsiterator = lists.iterator(); // The conversion mismatch here
            }
        }
        //..
    }
}
```

which produces a slightly more helpful error message:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.Iterator<java.util.List<T>> to java.util.Iterator<java.util.List<E>>

The solution is not to redeclare the type variable. Since `ListIterator` is an inner class it has access to the containing instance's `T`:

```
public class FlattenList<T> implements Iterable<T>{
    private List<List<T>> lists;
    public FlattenList(List<List<T>> list){
        this.lists = list;
    }
    public Iterator<T> iterator(){
        return new ListIterator();
    }
    class ListIterator implements Iterator<T>{
        private Iterator<List<T>> listsiterator;
        private Iterator<T> listiterator;
        public ListIterator(){
            if (lists != null) {
                listsiterator = lists.iterator(); // The conversion mismatch here
            }
        }
        //..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing the type parameter `T` from the `ListIterator` class fixes your problem. Namely:

```
class ListIterator implements Iterator<T> {
```

Even though those two type arguments are called the same (`T`), they actually are **not** the same. That's why you get so confusing message: `java.util.List<List<T>> cannot be cast to java.util.List<List<T>>` because those two T's were, I say it again, NOT the same.

Also this can be a fix:

```
public Iterator<T> iterator(){
    return new ListIterator(lists);
}
class ListIterator<T> implements Iterator<T>{
    private Iterator<List<T>> listsiterator;
    private Iterator<T> listiterator;
    public ListIterator(List<List<T>> listOfLists){
        if (listOfLists != null)
            listsiterator = listOfLists.iterator(); // The conversion mismatch here
        }
    }
}
```